# ClusterRole for CSI drivers

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, csi

I'm designing my own CSI driver and I'm wondering about needed role to be used for Kubernetes RBAC API.

The question is: am I forced to define my service specifying ClusterRole?

I made some trials and I couldn't manage to avoid it.

Thanks in advance to anyone will support,
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you do need to supply the `ClusterRole`

#### Here is an example of whats need to be done

- Follow those objects to have a full understanding of the required resources
  https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/external-provisioner/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/rbac.yaml